# Imported blog page layout messed

Tags: widgets, import, blog-page, blogger

http://uma.lohray.com/weblog/moots-part-ii/

is a blog I imported from blogger. The front page is fine, but when one clicks to read a blog post, the end of the post has parts of the right side bar widgets. I tried different templates, but the problem persists. I exported the blog as .xm and tried to see the data in the CDATA section to look for malignant tags, but it seems fine. Any new posts I make from wordpress are also messed in the blog page.

I am at my wits end on fixing this :-(

I am running a multi-site network.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your browser source code; the bad code has to do with a plugin called wpui-related-posts. Do you have that activated?

You can find/replace the code with a plugin called [Search RegEx.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) Use grep to match the strings and delete it all.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. As a matter of fact, I do see it in the code. But is not something I have installed. How do I fix it? I am looking forward for minimal hacks to avoid upgrade troubles.